# Failed to create JVM in Eclipse

Tags: java

My Eclipse reports the error that it failed to create a Java virtual machine although I use it daily, and I didn't change anything. Below is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Answer (score 1):

I added 
-vm
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\javaw.exe

main problem is
"-vm" option should be given above "-vmargs"
It worked for me.